# Chat app not working using XMPP protocol - open-fire server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xmpp, chat, openfire

Am using following code to send text to user using XMPP protocol configured with open-fire server.. i sent message to my app using spark IM client here i can receive the message but i cant send the text again in chat.

```
NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
    [body setStringValue:msgContent];

    NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"nik@182.17.0.162"];
    [message addChild:body];
    NSLog(@"message: %@", message);
    [xmppStream sendElement:message];
```

this my code and my message structure is:

```
<message type="chat" to="nik@182.17.0.162"><body>rtytry</body></message>
```

my text is not posting to selected user.

Any suggestion ?.. am i doing anything wrong here..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I would guess: The IP in `to=` attribute is wrong. There should go the service name, which is often the domain of the xmpp server or in case of openfire: Whatever is configured as `xmpp.domain` server property.

Comment: thing is that i configured my ip as my xmpp.domain(hostname).. So my userid for login is nik@172.16.0.162.. i think that is not the problem

Comment: You could confirm this by configuring a name as xmpp.domain.

Comment: using ip address as xmpp.domain will cause the problem..?

Comment: Not sure, never tried this setup. But I would give it a try. Also enable openfire's debug log and search **all** openfire logs for errors about this chat message.

Comment: :i dnt know for some reason all my open-fire logs are empty and i tried with domain name instead of ip but no change

Comment: is it i have to set message id and thread session in message xml tag..??